# How to build an easy to use cloud architecture

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, terraform, cloud, cluster-computing

I'm a student and I'm supposed to set up a usable cluster for the university in the next semester. The main requirement is that other students can easily work with it. The cluster consists of 20 Linux PCs and 20 Macs. Other students should be able to quickly get applications like Kubernetes, Hadoop, etc. running with little configuration. At best deploy application, determine the node number and done (exaggerated). What is the best way to do this. I've skimmed over tools like Ansible and Terraform, they sound like something im looking for, but don't know anything about them.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such questions are generally discouraged since they are not really questions but rather design problems but I'll answer anyway just to give you some idea.

1. Keep in mind that an architecture with 40 machines is not something easy to achieve for a beginner, so you should have a lot of patience and dedication when working on the project.
2. You are looking for a design type which is generally referred to as `Infrastructure as a Service - IaaS`. This allows tenants (the users of the cloud) to be able to deploy their own application/clusters on top of an existing infrastructure that you will provide. For this, you will have to start with something like `openstack`, which is one of the ways in which you can achieve this and you will have to do a lot of work to learn how it works, deploy it, and add your 40 machines to it. You can get started [here](https://www.openstack.org/). [I'm really unsure if you can use Mac systems as part of a cloud - but I'm really curious to know if it is possible]
3. Once you have setup an `openstack` infrastructure, you will have to think about maintenance and management of your system. There, you will have to think about solutions like `ansible` and `terraform` that will allow you to provide easy to use templates to you students where they will be able to edit some text files to match their specifications, and then deploy them on top of your `openstack` infrastructure easily. This practice is known as `Infrastructure as Code - IaC`. This helps you maintain your infrastructure designs as simple text files in a VCS (Version Control System) like Git for easier maintenance/rollback/upgrade etc.

The overall flow will look like this:

```
Student => Creates Manifests => Applies them to an Openstack account => Manages/Uses/Interacts with the deployed application

You => deploy Openstack => manage student accounts (tenant projects) => Monitor it => Maintain it => make sure it is available => Provide templates for deploying the 'overclouds'
```

There is no easy and simple answer to this very generic and complicated problem, but it is possible, for sure. I hope this gets you started.